Klein Gordon equation 1+1d driven by point time-oscillating source $\cos(\Omega t)\delta(x)$
Consider the classical Klein Gordon equation in 1+1d, $(\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2-a^2)\phi=\cos(\Omega t)\delta(x)$, where $a$ is real. The formal solution is, $$\phi(x,t)=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\int \frac{dq}{2\pi} e^{iqx-i\omega t} \frac{\delta(\omega-\Omega)+\delta(\omega+\Omega)}{(\omega+i0)^2-q^2-a^2}, $$
where I have used the frequency-momentum-space retarded Green's function, $-1/((\omega+i0)^2-q^2-a^2)$ with $i0$ denoting a positive imaginary infinitesimal. On simplifying,
$$\phi(x,t)=-\int \frac{dq}{2\pi} e^{iqx}\bigg(\frac{e^{-i\Omega t}}{2} \frac{1}{(\Omega+i0)^2-q^2-a^2}+\frac{e^{+i\Omega t}}{2} \frac{1}{(-\Omega+i0)^2-q^2-a^2}\bigg).$$
Case 1: For $a>\Omega$, $(a,\Omega>0)$,
$$\phi(x,t)=+\cos(\Omega t)\int \frac{dq}{2\pi} e^{iqx} \frac{1}{q^2+(a^2-\Omega^2)}=\cos(\Omega t)\frac{e^{-\sqrt{a^2-\Omega^2}|x|}}{2\sqrt{a^2-\Omega^2}}.$$
[Question 1] It seems in this case, since there aren't any poles, we can neglect the $i0$. It seems to me that somehow the causality arising from the retarded Green's function has vanished, which seems weird. It could be the case that the cosine source here is present since eternity, as opposed to a source which has a finite support in time domain. So we always have a response, with the causality not being obvious.
Case 2: For $a<\Omega$, $(a,\Omega>0)$,
\begin{align}
\phi(x,t)=&\int \frac{dq}{2\pi} e^{iqx}\bigg(\frac{e^{-i\Omega t}}{2} \frac{1}{q^2-((\Omega+i0)^2-a^2)}+\frac{e^{+i\Omega t}}{2} \frac{1}{q^2-((-\Omega+i0)^2-a^2)}\bigg),\\
=&\int \frac{dq}{2\pi} e^{iqx}\bigg(\frac{e^{-i\Omega t}}{2} \frac{1}{q^2-(\Omega^2-a^2)-i0}+\frac{e^{+i\Omega t}}{2} \frac{1}{q^2-(\Omega^2-a^2)+i0}\bigg),\\
=&\int \frac{dq}{2\pi} e^{iqx}\bigg(\frac{e^{-i\Omega t}}{2} \frac{1}{(q-\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}-i0)(q+\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}+i0)}+\frac{e^{+i\Omega t}}{2} \frac{1}{(q-\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}+i0)(q+\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}-i0)}\bigg),\\
=&i \frac{e^{-i\Omega t}}{2}\bigg[ e^{i\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}x}\Theta(x)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}} + e^{-i\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}x}\Theta(-x)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}}\bigg] + i \frac{e^{+i\Omega t}}{2} \bigg[ -e^{i\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}x}\Theta(x)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}} - e^{-i\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}x}\Theta(-x)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}}\bigg],\\
=&\sin(\Omega t)\bigg[ -e^{i\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}x}\Theta(x)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}} - e^{-i\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}x}\Theta(-x)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}}\bigg],\\
=&\sin(\Omega t)\frac{\cos(\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}|x|)}{2\sqrt{\Omega^2-a^2}}.
\end{align}
[Question 2] Does this look correct? The response is out-of-phase in time domain, which is in line with the phase shift behaviour across a resonance for a damped simple harmonic oscillator (damping is infinitesimal here).
